# Content BUILDER API bulk edit

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, content-builder, salesforce-classic

It's possible to use API to bulk edit files in Content Builder? What about classic content? If so, is there an already built product that does that? In particular I would like to replace part of a path in thousands of files.